# Copying conditional formatting in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In google sheets is there a way to copy just the conditional format without copying the cell that is being validated?  Meaning

I have a value in E2:E37

I want to create a conditional format rule
IF E2 < D2 Fill Color Green
IF E2 > D2 Fill Color Red

Instead of creating this rule on each cell in E3-E37 I want to copy the rule, however, when I do copy -> paste special -> conditional formatting only It will copy the rule but validate against the cell in which its being copied from.

Apply to range will change from E2:E3
Formula will remain at =D2

Comment: It looks like if I choose the entire range E2:E37 and then use the relative reference for the D column that the conditional formatting works, however, it looks like there is a bug that it displays that it is validating against the initial cell D2.

Answer (score 1):

Using the $ sign in front of the letter E and D to anchor just the columns should work. You would use the "custom formula is" option and enter the following formula:

```
=$E2>$D2 //select green highlighting
```

and then create an additional rule:

```
=$D2>$E2 //select red highlighting
```

You would then copy the cells with the formatting and then highlight the cells below you would like to format and select paste special > paste conditional formatting.

Comment: thanks, didn't realize it would recognize that in CF